# Zsh Alt+r not working for undo all changes

Tags: zsh

I am new to zsh but have found that pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> doesn't undo all changes to a line like in bash which I find very useful. The closest I have found so far is pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> repeatedly but I much rather have it done in one go.

Does zsh have such a function that can undo all changes to a line like in bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zsh does not have such a feature out of the box, but it's easy enough to create one:

```bash
revert-line() {                          
  while zle .undo; do done
}
zle -N revert-line 
bindkey '^[r' revert-line
```